# I'm trying to figure out why the first class in my css is taking precedence

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out why the first class in my css is taking precedence, I thought if you call two classes, the last class gets the call.

Here is my example:
    
    
    
    
    Test CSS Precedence`enter code here`

```
<style>
/* Scenario 1 */ 
.blue { color:blue; };`enter code here`
.red { color:red; };
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="red blue">Red Blue</div> <!-- CSS Specifity (0,0,2,1) -->
<div class="blue red">Blue Red</div> <!-- CSS Specifity (0,0,2,1) -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The CSS is invalid, it should look something like this:

```
.blue { color:blue; }
.red { color:red; }
```

Take a look at [CSS syntax documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/). The semi-colon `;` shouldn't appear outside of the curly brackets. Because of this error, the styling from `.red` wasn't being applied to any elements at all.

Aside from that; a stylesheet is cascade. It is read from top to bottom, therefore if an element contains both classes (regardless of order), `.red` will still overwrite `.blue` because it appears later in the stylesheet. [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzWqs/)

Comment: Thanks JoshC, I overlooked the semi-colon in my code.  It's always good to have a 2nd pair of eyes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Josh said, the later specified attribute is the one that will have greater importance. Have a read through this article on CSS specificity if you'd like further clarification.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thanks Longblog, because of the invalid CSS, that was the root issue, as I know the CSS Specifity pretty well and wasn't sure why the first class was showing when I new the 2nd class should show.  Thanks for your URL link too, always great to get additional help from others.